# Render stop-motion video from Wavefront *.obj files

Tags: windows, gratis, video, modeling

I auto-generate a sequence of ~100 [Wavefront *.obj files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) with a script which I would like to turn into a stop-motion video.

#### Requirements

- Availability of a CLI or API so that the whole process can be automated.
- Customization of the render scene, e.g. the camera perspective and lighting adjustments.
  Being able to use same settings for all files in a sequence is sufficient.
- Video output in any reasonably common format

#### Bonus features

- Support for a 3D file format supporting colors, e.g. [*.(c)off files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OFF_(file_format)).
- Interpolation between the object files.

#### Available software

- ["Stop motion OBJ" Blender addon](https://github.com/neverhood311/Stop-motion-OBJ): It fulfills all requirements, however, it requires user interaction as far as the README describes it.
- [Batch rendering of *.obj files with Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/80938/827): I could use that script to produce a sequence of image files which then need to be turned into a video.

Answer (score 0):

This answer represents a bit of a convoluted process, but I believe it would work for you and meets a couple of your requirements.

OpenSCAD is a free program that allows for command line interface. OpenSCAD also has a [feature involving animation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/The_OpenSCAD_User_Interface#Animation). This particular link is rather limited with respect to useful information, but my search results for "OpenSCAD animation" resulted in too many from which to choose. Most of the other links were far more comprehensive, including one from [Instructables](https://www.instructables.com/id/Animating-with-OpenSCAD/).

One complication in this answer is that the files would have to be converted from .OBJ to .STL in order to be imported and processed. I suspect there are CLI programs capable of doing batch conversions to make that portion easier, but I did not research it.

Additionally, the output is going to be one image in .PNG format per frame, which would have to be converted to .GIF or loaded into a video editor to create "standard" video. There's a [web site](https://bryanduxbury.com/2014/01/16/creating-animated-gifs-from-openscad/) in which this process is explained in a limited manner which involves using [ImageMagick convert utility](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) which is a CLI.

[image: animation from OpenSCAD]

The animation above is from the linked web site. A number of features of OpenSCAD have been implemented in this example, as the rendered objects are usually single color and not semi-transparent.